# Can't resize svg picture in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, svg

I need to make an svg image size like on the photo below

[image]

But when i'm trying to give this size through SvgPicture.asset constructor or with a SizedBox it doesn't make any effect and i'm getting something like this

[image]

here is my code of that widget

```
Container(
            width: 80,
            height: 80,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
              gradient: yellowGradient,
            ),
            child: SizedBox(
              height: 29,
              width: 45,
              child: SvgPicture.asset(
                dishIconPath,
                color: whiteIconColor,
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

I think that my Svg picture stretches to container size but i don't know what causes such a behaviour because there is SizedBox

Comment: Please try loading PNG instead of SVG

Comment: Wrap your SizedBox with a FittedBox

Comment: wrapping with a FittedBox didn't help

Answer (score 3):

`Container` doesn't know how to align the child if it is smaller than the container itself, so it expands it to fill the containers size.

The `SizedBox` can also be removed as `SvgPicture.asset(...)` now accepts size parameters.

Based on the above information, a possible solution for you will be the following, the important bit being the addition of `alignment: Alignment.center`:

```
Container(
    width: 80,
    height: 80,
    alignment: Alignment.center,
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(20),
        gradient: yellowGradient,
    ),
    child: SvgPicture.asset(
        dishIconPath,
        color: whiteIconColor,
        height: 29,
        width: 45,
    ),
),
```

For further information, refer to "Layout behaviour" in the Container widget [documentation here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Container-class.html).

Answer (score 1):

you can use padding or margin

```
Container(
  width: 40,
  height: 40,
  padding: const EdgeInsets.all(15),
  child: SvgPicture.asset(
    "assets/icons/outline/edit2.svg",
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of wrapping it with a `SizedBox`, use the fields `height` and `width` of the `SvgPicture`.

```dart
SvgPicture.asset(
  dishIconPath,
  color: whiteIconColor,
  height: 29,
  width: 45,
),
```

Comment: i wrote that i've tried to change height and with through it's constructor and got the same issue

Comment: ran into the same problem... did you solve this?i use it as background, but alas allways the whole image is shown...